# Не работает объединение в c#

Tags: c#

Делаю объединение float и четырёх байт, идущие друг за другом в памяти

```
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public struct time
    {
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(0)]
        public float as_float;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(0)]
        public byte high_byte;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(1)]
        public byte second_byte;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(2)]
        public byte third_byte;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(3)]
        public byte low_byte;
    };
time t1, t2;
```

label5.Text += t1.as_float; - результат NaN

label5.Text += t1.high_byte; - всё ок

Что делаю не так? Сделано на основе примера с сайта Майкрософт

Comment: Так а что за значение в t1 ?

Answer (score 3):

Обратите внимание на порядок хранения байтов. А именно:

Перепишем вашу структуру так:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct time
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int AsInt;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public byte First;

    [FieldOffset(1)]
    public byte Second;

    [FieldOffset(2)]
    public byte Third;

    [FieldOffset(3)]
    public byte Fourth;
};
```

и теперь:

```
time t1 = new time { First = 16, Second = 15, Third = 14, Fourth = 13 };
Console.WriteLine(t1.AsInt);  // 219 025 168
Console.WriteLine(t1.AsInt.ToString("X4"));  // D0E0F010
```